# "semi-pseudonorm" in references

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

The following is an excerpt of a note in topological vector spaces.

[image]

I have tried to search "semi-pseudonorm" on Google but I have got nothing so far. A search with "pseudonorm" returns what we usually call "[seminorm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seminorm.html)". Does anybody see the term "semi-pseudonorm" or "pseudonorm" defined in the way as the note shows in other references? Or are these two concepts equivalent to something more familiar to the people working in functional analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\sp{\kern.4mm}$The *semi-pseudonorm* in the cited reference is precisely what for example Jarchow (p. 38, Locally Convex Spaces, Teubner 1981) calls an *F-seminorm*.

**Added.** (20.9.2015) Besides the one given in Gerald Edgar's answer, another example is $[\sp x\sp]\mapsto\int_0^1|\sp x(t)\sp|\sp(1+|\sp x(t)\sp|\sp)^{-1}{\sp\rm d\sp}t$ in the space $L^0\big([\,0\sp,1\,]\big)$ of all (equivalence classes of real or complex valued) measurable functions on $[\,0\sp,1\,]$ defining the topology for which convergent sequences are precisely those converging *[in measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Topology)*.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your example is $\mathcal L^{1/2}[0,1]$:  The space of measurable functions $f \;:\; [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that the expression
$$
p(f) := \int_0^1 |f(t)|^{1/2} dt
$$
is finite.  And this becomes the space $L^{1/2}[0,1]$ when you identify functions that agree almost everywhere, and you get (4).  Another way to treat $L^{1/2}$ is to use
$$
q(f) := \big(\int_0^1 |f(t)|^{1/2} dt\big)^2
$$
Then you recover ($1')$ $q(\lambda x) = |\lambda|\;q(x)$ but lose (3) $q(x) + q(y) \le q(x+y)$.  Of course both $p$ and $q$ give you the same topololgy for the space.

For the question.  I don't know of work using the name "semi-pseudonorm" for this.

For $L^{1/2}$ and friends, maybe try: Kalton, Peck & Roberts, *An F-Space Sampler*